# Нужна ли нам вёрстка?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

<strike>У нас есть метка [вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), по ней живёт совсем немного вопросов (всего 77 на момент написания вопроса). И я в ней не вижу смысла, так как всю "вёрстку" можно прекрасно найти по метке [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), и вот по ней уже живёт более 7000 вопросов.</strike>

Предлагаю её удалить. Но если примем решение оставить, тогда буду покрывать все (ну если не все, так почти все) вопросы по [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) меткой [вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0). Ибо всё что [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) — это [вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0). Если не согласны, приводите контрпримеры.

#### UPDATE

У метки [вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) теперь более 1к вопросов и будет ещё больше. Теперь она совсем нередкая. И она действительно уникальна и заслуживает право на существование (спасибо за ответы и комментарии, которые помогли мне изменить своё мнение). Ужа начинаю и буду продолжать её активно навешивать её на новые и существующие вопросы по вёрстке.

Comment: Какую именно проблему вызывает существование тега [tag:верстка]? Т.е. вот мы потратим время и вырежем эту метку из 77 старых вопросов - кто получит от этого пользу?  "Я люблю чистоту и просто хочу удалять те метки, которые лично мне не нравятся" - плохой аргумент. Их станет проще найти? На них станут чаще приходить из поисковиков? Решения в них станут лучше от удаления метки?

Comment: @PashaPash Я могу не вырезать эту метку. Я могу добавить её во все вопросы по [tag:css] и будет в принципе уместно. Аргумент — чистая избыточность, так как можно использовать другую метку [tag:css]. Что скажете?

Comment: Да, я понимаю что вы любите чистоту и не любите избыточность. Но вы не ответили на вопросы из моего комментария :). В чем проблема избыточности? Если мы уберем избыточность - вопросы и ответы станет проще найти? На них станут чаще приходить из поисковиков? Решения в них станут лучше от удаления избыточной метки?

Comment: Наличие метки, кстати, никак не влияет на читабельность вопроса - по крайней мере, она шумит не больше, чем 5 текстовых пунтков меню прямо под метками.

Comment: Отлично, ваш вердикт: добавим во все вопросы, связанные с вёрсткой, верно?

Comment: Если человек спрашивает об анимации в css. Как она работает, допустим, то причем тут будет вёрстка? А если о том, как делаются фигуры на css? в целом. Не как это организовать в шаблоне, в html и прикрепить сбоку, а о самой технике, механизме работы, то причём тут вёрстка? А о том на сколько какая-нибудь анимация ресурсозатратна? И таких вопросов много может быть.

Comment: Хорошо, добавим везде, где есть вёрстка, верно? css-анимации и фигуры не трогаем:) Поверьте, я по мере сил подобавляю.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет. мой вердикт - не трогать метки если они не создают проблемы. не добавлять и не убирать. Правки должны улучшать читабельность и доступность вопроса. Если они ее не улучшают - они бесполезны и бессмысленны.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov на всякий случай - почитайте http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work - там перечислены причины, по которым стоит сжигать метки. "tag implies no clearly defined meaning" - нет для верстки, "tag has a clearly defined meaning, but is still misused often" - нет для верстки.

Comment: @PashaPash Смотрите, если я подобавляю метки "верстка", там где вопрос по "вёрстке", то я согласно вашей логике увеличу доступность вопроса, верно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет, потому что метка верстка - редкая. Вы повысите доступность вопроса в случае, если добавите популярную метку [tag:css] на вопрос, где уже стоит [tag:верстка] (добавите или замените ей метку [tag:верстка] - без разницы). Но не наоборот - если вы добавите редкий [tag:верстка] на вопрос, где уже стоит [tag:css] - доступность вопроса не поменяется.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov и кстати, [tag:верстка] и [tag:вёрстка] - внезапно разные тэги. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-css и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-css - вот вам два списка для редактирования и улучшения.

Comment: @PashaPash Да тут можно синонимом решить то, что они разные.

Comment: @PashaPash Давайте вот так вопрос задам: если я и может ещё кто-то начнёт добавлять метку "вёрстка" в большое количество вопросов и сделает метку "вёрстка" нередкой — это будет нарушениями правил?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если этот кто-то при этом исправляет все проблемы в редактируемых сообщениях - то ок, правила не будут нарушены. Хотя сам факт добавления метки при такой правке будет достаточно бессмысленным. Если этот кто-то просто будет лепить метку, не исправляя остальных проблем поста - он или получит edit ban (если правки проходят ревью) или подвергнется общественному порицанию на мете.

Comment: @PashaPash Да без проблем. Сделаете [tag:верстка] синонимом [tag:вёрстка]? Если можно, то именно так, так как написание с "ё" предпочтительней.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov готово

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov кстати, на одном из вопросов стояли обе метки :)

Comment: @PashaPash У метки вёрстка теперь более 1к вопросов и будет ещё больше. Теперь она совсем нередкая.

Comment: Верстка - не только css ведь. Верстка - это html + css, и html правильно, что стоит первее. 
А по поводу чистоты, то Господи, серьезно? Я хотел бы чтобы тегов было пару миллиардов и ещё бесконечность между этими двумя  слоями миллиардов тегов. Бесчисленное количество раз встречаешь такое, что на англоязычном СО есть тег, который мне нужен, а на ру-СО - его нет. И не знаешь что писать, а если не впихнешь бывает тег, то и вовсе вопрос будет послан куда дальше. Клево. Зато чистота.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть множество вопросов включающих являющихся вопросами по css, но не являющихся вопросами верстки.
Скажем вот:
[Webpack. Сборка отдельных css и скриптов в общие файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605742/webpack-%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-css-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Есть множество вопросов по html, но не являющихся вопросами верстки.
Скажем вот:
 [Где в спецификациях W3C отражена возможность использования document.body?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611660/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-w3c-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-document-body)

Я бы оставил, метка несет свой уникальный смысл и может быть полезна, другое дело что вопросы по верстке часто достойны навешивания тегов html и css и не на всех вопросах по верстке есть эта метка.

Comment: Ну тогда давайте "довешивать" на все вопросы по теме вёрстки.

Answer (score -2):

Да пусть остаётся. Может пригодится потом.

Хочу иерархию меток выпросить :)

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что иерархия будет. Уже поднимался этот вопрос и безуспешно. Но тут это разные множества, иерархия в данном случае совсем не подойдёт. Я смотрел и редактировал вопросы по [tag:html] и [tag:css]. Далеко не ко всем подходит [tag:вёрстка]. Ещё видел [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604895/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), на который [tag:css] не подходит, а вот [tag:вёрстка] — в самый раз.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, конкретно этот вопрос я тоже видел - в принципе, ему и без вёрстки неплохо. Он был первым в 195 по запросам из соседнего ответа.

Answer (score -3):

На мой взгляд кажется, что можно синонимизировать [верстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) c [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Сейчас вопросов с этими тегами 913+77=990.

В таком случае в 368+31=399 появится [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). Возможно, стоит обратить на них внимание:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/верстка+-html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-html)
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/вёрстка+-html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-html)

Если синонимизировать с css, то, внезапно, останется 256+29=285 вопросов:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/верстка+-css+-css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-css+-css3)
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/вёрстка+-css+-css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-css+-css3)

Не по теме, но надо что-то с этими 253 вопросами делать:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3+-css

Кстати, 177+18=195 вопросов помечены вёрсткой без каких-либо html или css:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/верстка+-html+-html5+-css+-css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-html+-html5+-css+-css3)
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/вёрстка+-html+-html5+-css+-css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+-html+-html5+-css+-css3)

PS: А вообще, может и не трогать её. Лучше бы иерархию меток запилили.

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что [tag:вёрстка] и [tag:html] — это синонимы. Парсинг HTML, конвертация из\в HTML и т.д. — это не вёрстка. По поводу синонимов с [tag:css] смотрите [ответ @УткаУчитсяУму](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4544/220571) и [комментарий @АлексейШиманский](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4541/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0/4544#comment15828_4541)

Comment: Бывает еще верстка в мобайле.